# Structuring a combination of 'functions' in a cohesive manner

Tags: php

My application needs to use a bunch of variations of the code below. There are roughly six or seven variations of the code below, but I'm having trouble organizing them.
At first, I created a class and separated them into functions but for some reason all of the functions stopped working. Just glancing over the code below, do you see maybe a good way to organize something like this?

```
try{
    $fql = "select uid,name,education from user WHERE uid IN (select uid2 from friend where uid1=($user_id))";
    $param  =   array(
        'method'    => 'fql.query',
        'query'     => $fql,
        'callback'  => ''
    );
    $fqlResult   =   $facebook->api($param);
}
catch(Exception $o){
    d($o);
}

$friends = $fqlResult;
$friends_BA = array();

foreach ($friends as $friend) {
    $isBA = false;
    if (is_array($friend['education'])) {
        foreach ($friend['education'] as $school) {
            if (isset($school['concentration'])) {
                foreach ($school['concentration'] as $concentration) {
                    if (strpos(strtolower($concentration['name']), 'business') !== false) {
                        $friends_BA[] = $friend['name'];
                        continue 3; // skip to the next friend
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

d($friends_BA);
```

Comment: Use a class. If the functions stopped working, check what was wrong and make them work.

Comment: In order to provide a more generic solution, people need to know what varies between the variations. Be specific.

Comment: Basically I had to add all of the Facebook Graph API configuration code to every single function to get them all to work. So altogether it'll be about 500 lines of code in one class.

Comment: Do you really have a function called d()?

Answer (score 0):

```
  function getLocalFriends () {
             $config = array(
             'appId' => 'XXXXXXXXXX',
             'secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
             );
             $facebook = new Facebook($config);
             $user_id = $facebook->getUser();
             try {
             $fql    =   "select name,current_location from user WHERE uid IN (select uid2 from friend where uid1=($user_id))";
             $param  =   array(
             'method'    => 'fql.query',
             'query'     => $fql,
             'callback'  => ''
             );
             $fqlResult   =   $facebook->api($param);
             }
                 catch(Exception $o){
             d($o);
             }

             $friends = $fqlResult;
             $friends_BA = array();
             foreach ($friends as $friend) {
               $isBA = false;
               if (is_array($friend['current_location'])) {
                  $lowerName = strtolower($friend['current_location']['city']);
                      if (strpos($lowerName, 'orlando') !== false || strpos($lowerName, 'altamonte springs') !== false) {
                      $friends_BA[] = $friend['name'];
            }
         }
       }
             echo '<pre>';
             print_r($friends_BA);
             echo '</pre>';
}
```